# TFS 2013: Checking what projects a user has access to

Tags: team-foundation-server

I often need to give a user, A, access to the same projects as another user, B.

How can I do this without having to ask user B what projects he has access to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Web Access for this purposes:

1. Navigate to TFS Control Panel
2. Select project collection
3. Click "Manage collection security and group membership" under "Administration tasks"
4. On the opened Security tab select users sub-tab
5. Activate Member Of tab

[image: List TFS user roles]